# A lonely pawn on the chessboard

Tags: mathematics, strategy, probability, game, checkerboard

Alice and Bob and the referee Conny play the following game with a pawn on a standard $8\times8$ chessboard:

- In the beginning, Conny places the pawn into the center of a randomly chosen square. All $64$ squares are chosen with equal probabilities.
- Then Alice and Bob alternate turns; Alice starts.
- In every turn, the pawn is moved to a new square. The pawn is always placed into the very center of a square.
- The (Euclidean straight line) distance moved by the pawn must be strictly larger than the (Euclidean straight line) distance moved by the pawn in any of the preceding moves.
- A player unable to move loses the game.

> **Question:** What is the probability that Alice wins this game?
>   (As usual, we assume that Alice and Bob both use optimal strategies.)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Alice wins with 100% probability.

Strategy:

> On each of her turns Alice will place the pawn onto the square which is exactly opposite of the original square over the center of the board.
>  Now Bob will have to move the pawn further than Alice did and will involuntarily end up being closer to a corner than Alice was before.
>  With every turn Alice will not change the minimum distance to one of the corners while Bob will get closer and closer.

How this works:

> Lets look at it from the end of the game:
>  The person who jumps from one corner of the board to the opposite corner (for example **A1** to **H8**) will win, because the opponent can't make a longer jump than that.
>  The person who jumps into a corner first will lose, because the opponent can jump into the opposite corner afterwards.
>  The only way to force your opponentinto the corner is if you jumped from a square directly next to a corner to the opposite square (for example **A2** to **H7**).
>  Therefore the first person to jump onto a square directly next to a corner will lose because the opponent can from there on out force the moves.
>  And so on and so forth.

Comment: I think you're right, but your expression of the solution is not clear at all and relies on the reader to fill in a lot of details and resolve ambiguities like what the "original square" means.

Answer (score 12):

> Alice always wins. If Alice is at $q$, her winning strategy is to hop to $q'$, such that the midpoint of $q$ and $q'$ is the center of the board.
>
>  We need only prove that this move is always legal for Alice to make. Since she never is without a legal move, she wins.
>
>  She can certainly do this on her first move.
>  For other moves, let $p'$ and $q'$ be the opposites of $p$ and $q$, respectively, as defined above. Suppose Alice has just hopped from $p$ to $p'$, and then Bob hopped from $p'$ to $q$. Let $o$ be the center of the board. Finally, let $d(a,b)$ mean the distance between points $a$ and $b$, and recall the triangle inequality $d(a,c)\le d(a,b)+d(b,c)$, for any $a,b,c$.
>
>  First, we show that $d(q,o)>d(p',o)$. Supposing not, it would follow that
>
>  $$d(p',q)\le d(p',o)+d(o,q)\le d(p',o)+d(o,p')=d(p',p),$$
>
>  but $d(p',q)\le d(p',p)$ contradicts the fact that it was legal for Bob to hop from $p'$ to $q$.
>
>  With this fact under our belts, we know have that
>
>  $$d(p',q)\le d(p',o)+d(q,o)<d(q,o)+d(q,o)=d(q,q')$$
>
>  This proves that it is legal for Alice to hop from $q$ to $q'$.

Answer (score 8):

For an $m\times n$ board.

If $m$ or $n$ is even:

> Alice can win with 100% probability using @TheDarkTruth's [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/24137/5434).

If both $m$ and $n$ are odd:

> Given an optimal strategy from both players,  Alice will win with 100% probability all games where she start off-centre and lose with 100% probability the games where she starts in the centre of the board; so her overall probability is $\frac{mn-1}{mn}$.

Explanation:

> In the case of starting in the exact centre of the board, Alice initially moves the pawn out of the centre then Bob can then follow @TheDarkTruth's [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/24137/5434) with the roles reversed).
>  An $8 \times 8$ board always gives the first player a 100% probability of winning as the pawn will always start off-centre.

Comment: There is no centre of an 8x8 board.

Comment: Yes - I noted that in the explanation section. This was expanding the question to the general case of a MxN board rather than just an 8x8 board.